# Como formatar uma data para o formato brasileiro em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, data, formatação

Como faço para formatar uma data para o padrão brasileiro em JavaScript? Procurei em diversos lugares mas não consegui fazer com que a data fosse exibida no padrão brasileiro.

Resumo do problema:

- Como a data está no banco de dados: `2021-02-05 04:30:25`
- Como eu queria que a data fosse exibida no return: `05/02/2021 04:30:25`

A parte do código que preciso fazer isso está aqui embaixo, caso alguém entenda melhor:

```
{
"render": function ( data, type, row ) {

    var dataCadastro = '2021-02-05 04:30:25'; // Formatar essa data para o padrão brasileiro > dd/mm/aaaa
    return dataCadastro; // retorna a data definida acima

    },
    "targets": 1,
},
```

Comment: Para isso e outras funcionalidades recomendo usar a lib moment.js

Comment: Meu projeto possui o moment.js integrado, porém não faço a menor ideia de como utilizar heheh poderia me dar uma ajuda?      <script src="../all/plugins/moment/moment.min.js"></script>

Comment: Veja se a resposta ajuda.